# How do I stop circular "followers" in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

Basically, I have a table with two columns, a follower and a followed. If a user1 follows user2, I need to make sure user2 cannot follow user1. What do I write in the model to validate that?

I have a User model where each one has an id. I also created a new Relationship model, where there are the two columns.

This is where I'm at.

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :followed_id, :follower_id

belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"

validates :followed_id, presence: true
validates :follower_id, presence: true
validates :verify_no_circular_requirements

private
  def verify_no_circular_requirements
    return true
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this is being downvoted primarily because of the title. I could edit it for you, but you should be able to come up with something more explanatory.

Comment: John you're getting down voted because you have given no indication of what you've tried. You stand a better chance of getting a reply if you test some things and then ask a question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem, all **relevant** error messages exactly as they appear, and whatever samples you're testing against.

Comment: Hey guys, yeah sorry about that. I hope the new title is good enough. I didn't know how to phrase it in a single question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom validator function:

For example(assumption, you have a followed_users method which returns all the users that the current user is following, and a follow method, taking a user id and "following this user.):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :users, inverse_of :user, as: followed_users
    validates :verify_no_circular_followers

    def followed
       followed_users
    end

   def follow(user_id)
      followed_users << User.find(user_id)
   end

   private
      def verify_no_circular_followers
          followed_users.each do |u|
             if u.index(self)
                return false
             end
          end
          return true
      end
end
```

Comment: Where am I supposed to write this followed_users method? in the controller where I would supposedly create a new follow?

Comment: I would probably use a self referential has_many and set it up directly on the model. See my edit above.